# Javascript JSON - sort the array items which are objects

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

Pls refer - http://jsfiddle.net/cbe6vxgh/2/

```
var datax = $("#x").val();
var e = JSON.parse(datax);
```

Requirement is to sort the JSON data based on the bdate, as given in fiddle.
sorting has to be done only in pure javascript.

I thought of forEach loop, and all, but was not able to sort it.

Comment: Please include relevant code in the question itself. There are also [code snippets](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) which will allow you to keep all the same fiddle-like functionality

Comment: `e.sort(function (a, b) { return a.bdate < b.bdate; })`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript

Comment: What's your question? Where's your data? Put your code *in the question*. Links to external sites tend to go stale. Also, since you are already using jquery, why the "pure" javascript restriction?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant it's correct that the OP should use `.sort()` but the comparator function must return an integer (negative, positive, or zero).

Comment: @Pointy alright, I always forget that it's the sloppy C-style "total ordering required" comparison function…

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var datax = $("#x").val();
var e = JSON.parse(datax);

function compare(a,b) {
  var da = a.birthday.split("/");
  da = new Date(da[2], da[0]-1, da[1]);
  var db = b.birthday.split("/");
  db = new Date(db[2], db[0]-1, db[1]);
  if (da < db)
     return -1;
  if (da > db)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

e.sort(compare);
console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cbe6vxgh/8/

Comment: @nikhilrao should work now, you need to convert date string to actual Date to compare.